Conditions on LR in Gradient Descent
In Introductory Lectures in Convex Optimization by Yurii Nesterov, Section 1.2.3 shows that gradient descent is guaranteed to converge if the step size is chosen either with a fixed step size or chosen by the Goldstein-Armijo rule.
Do you know if there exists conditions on a variable step size (upper/lower bounds?) which guarantees the convergence of gradient descent? (The conditions need not guarantee convergence to a local minimum, just to a stationary point). Thank you!

Can you be more specific? I am sure this plenty of literature out there already. Do you mean to choose the LR arbitrarily at each step but within a certain interval?

Not exactly - I'm working on a project for which I have an upper bound on the learning rate already and I want to ensure that gradient descent will still converge even if my upper bound gets small. Do you know if there are conditions on a variable step size, for example a maximum rate it decays, for which GD can still converge to a stationary point?

I think the usual condition will be that the step sizes are not summable. Check for example Bertsekas' Nonlinear Programming Proposition 1.2.3.
